# one way conditional statement in binary variable linearization

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, constraints, mixed-integer-programming, binary-programming

I am trying to write a one-way conditional statemen with binary variables. my condition is (x and y are both binary variables)

```
(if x=1 then y=0)
```

and it is the **only** condition that should be met. So I want to have:

```
(if x=0 then y=0 or 1)
(if x=1 then y=0)
(if y=0 then x=0 or 1)
(if y=1 then x=0 or 1)
```

the problem of using `y<=1-x` is that the statement is two-way(for x and y: (if x=1 then y=0) and (if y=1 then x=0) and I want to have **only** (if x=1 then y=0)).
I have already tried out large M and some of other methods which I knew, however I did not achieve any results. 
Can anyone please help me. I stuck on this problem for a couple of days...

Thank you

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Duplicate here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67919754/one-way-conditional-statement-in-binary-variable-linearization

Comment: When $x$ and $y$ are both binary, the contrapositive of $(x = 1) \implies (y = 0)$ is $(y = 1) \implies (x = 0)$. So the second and fourth of your four "wants" are incompatible.

Answer (score 0):

Such a condition cannot be of type $\phi(x,y) <= 0$

Indeed, such a condition would mean $\phi(1,1) > 0$, i.e. "(x,y) = (1,1) is forbidden", which is not equivalent to your "(if x=1 then y=0)"

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, I did not understand it. You mean it is not possible to model my problem? even if I use another binary like z=0 or 1?

Comment: wouldn't $z$ necessarily be phrased in terms of $x$ and $y$ ?

Comment: I am not native in English. Again sorry if I don't understand you. I am trying to solve it for couple of days and I could not. I have use large M, got help from another variable like z. And No, z is phrased not necessarily be phrased in terms of x "and" y. it could be phrased in terms of one of them, x "or" y. I do not know, but I tried different ways and no results. So, (and sorry for asking again), you mean it is not possible to model my problem?

Comment: What I am saying is that such a modelling of your problem cannot take the form of an inequality phrased solely in terms of $x$ and $y$. The reason for that is that precluding the case $(x,y) =(1,1)$ entails both the logical statements (if x=1 then y=0) and (if y=1 then x=0). I don't see how adding a new variable helps.

Comment: Ok, I appreciate your help. Pease inform me if you come up with any ideas. Thanks